# Use AngularJS to set URL to a variable

Tags: angularjs

http://jsfiddle.net/fhfepbtu/

I'd like to parse the current url and use the parsed values in the application.  How can I set a model variable to the current URL?

Here's the code from the fiddle link.

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  {{url}}
</div>
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);


function MyCtrl($scope, $window) {
    $scope.url = $window.location.href;
}
```

Displays...

> {{url}}

Comment: attach controller to your angular module myApp

Comment: would work fine if you implemented angular properly and don't use angular version 1.01. What are you needing from url? Angular already has `$location` service and routers add more available data objects

Comment: also need to fix typo in `location`

Comment: @charlietfl Fixing the typo seemed to do the trick.  I've edited the link. Thanks

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fhfepbtu/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a simple lexical error:

```
$scope.url = $window.locaton.href;
```

You put ***locaton*** instead ***location***.

Answer (score 1):

See documentation and examples here from angular. 
[angularjs.org $location](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location)

First implement your controller properly then you need to use the $location service like the following

```
myApp.controller("MyCtrl" ,["$scope","$window","$location", function($scope, $window, $location){
// Your controller code here..... 
$scope.url = $location.absUrl();
}]);
```

You can use $location.path(); to just get the last part of url or $location.absUrl(); to get the whole thing. Please read the linked documentation.

I edited the jsfiddle here [https://jsfiddle.net/hth8sm5y/3/](https://jsfiddle.net/hth8sm5y/1/)

> EDIT: As others have said there was also a typo in your code
>   "location" so fixing the typo fixes your code using $window. I'm not
>   sure what your usage is but I suggested $location because it allows
>   quick access to certain parts on the url like path() and hash() and
>   also provides both getter/setter.

Comment: thanks for responding.  I have tried using $location.path().  I couldn't get `this.urlSnippet` to display.  And when I typed `this.urlSnippet` into the chrome console it says 'undefined'.  Can your suggested answer be implemented in jsfiddle so I can see the full solution?